# How to extract HEX-encoded IP addresses from a binary?

Tags: python, android, extract

I'd like to know how to extract HEX-encoded IP addresses from a binary (any format - Win32/Win64/ELF/ARM) and convert to a human-readable ASCII.

For obvious reasons, it's not something that Linux "strings" or grep would find.

If, for example, "8.8.8.8" is compiled into a binary, it would probably look like a hex string

of "00 08 00 08 00 08 00 08" ? 
or "08 00 08 00 08 00 08 00" ?

Where can I read more about it or if there's any suitable tools for this?

The whole idea is to analyze different spyware and malware.
(Right now I'm trying to dissect Xiaomi MIUI Android binaries).
There is dozens of hardcoded IP addresses of Chinese CDN's where the firmware is trying to "phone back".

My idea is:

- extract resources/sections from a list of MIUI system binaries (binwalk)
- extract and convert all possible IP's (hex > ascii)
- remove the false positives (there will be tons of them)
- resolve, sort, check live hosts, clean the list
- patch the original binaries so that all spying IP's would point to 0.0.0.0
- publish it on Github :)

That's only one application, can be used for similar purposes.

What would you recommend to start with? Thanks!

P.S: I'm still learning so please advise a more optimal way.

Comment: Binary has 0 and 1 only, no 8.

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you consider to be a binary. Or where you encounter them.

Comment: I'm having a hard time making myself clear..... Maybe I have to reframe the question, so here it goes:

How exactly an IP address would be transcoded in a x86/amd64/arm executable file? How? If you open an executable with a HEX Editor, you're not going to see "1.1.1.1" or "8.8.8.8" across the compiled binary code. What you will see instead?